# Как запустить python скрипт на сайте, чтобы пользователь мог взаимодействовать с ним?

Tags: javascript, php, python, python-3.x

Мне нужна помощь, дело в том, что мне нужно сделать так, чтобы на сайте запускался py скрипт,желательно сделать это по кнопке. Нужно чтобы пользователь мог взаимодействовать с ним, то есть в py скрипте будут спрашиваться значения. 
И к python скрипту  прилагается еще файл, ну пусть будет config.txt, нужно чтобы пользователь мог туда добавлять значения. 
Как это сделать?

P.s на сайте используется wp(если это играет значение).

Comment: А какой сайт даёт запускать у себя скрипты Python?

Answer (score 1):

можно с помощью функции `exec()` с записью исходящих данных в массив.
например:

```
exec("python3.5 /PATH/TO/FILE/SCRIPT.py {$input_params_string}", $output_response_array);
print_r($output_response_array);
```

где `$input_params_string` строка данных, разделенных пробелом, например:

```
$input_params_string = implode(' ', array( // В этом случае ключи не будут переданы
    'user_id'       => 1,
    'user_pass'     => 123,
    'user_status'   => 'OK',
));
```

и обработанная на стороне Python-скрипта, например:

```
import sys

print(sys.argv[1]) #user_id
print(sys.argv[2]) #user_pass
print(sys.argv[3]) #user_status

print ("Hello World!")
```

Вся информация, выведенная функцией `print()` в Python-скрипте, будет записана в массив `$output_response_array` PHP-скрипта

Answer (score 0):

Возможно использовать CGI-скрипты на Python, если хостинг это поддерживает. На сколько я знаю, reg.ru и вроде как beget работают.

https://pythonworld.ru/web/cgi-1.html

Если знаете веб-фреймворк, по типу Flask и Django, то можете запустить их на отдельном порту и настроить прокси через nginx/apache.

Answer (score 0):

Недавно пробовал, тут https://github.com/alex-eri/jsterm

```py
import asyncio
from aiohttp import web
import aiohttp
import os
import pty
import fcntl


async def websocket_handler(request):
    ws = web.WebSocketResponse()
    await ws.prepare(request)
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    master, slave = pty.openpty() # создаем новую консоль
    name = os.ttyname(slave)
    pid = os.fork()  # отделяемся в новый процесс
    if pid == 0:
        os.setsid()
        os.dup2(slave,0) # подключаем его к созданной ранее консоли
        os.dup2(slave,1)
        os.dup2(slave,2)
        os._exit(os.execv('/usr/bin/ipython3',('python@ws', ))) # запускаем там програмку
        # os._exit(os.execv('/usr/bin/python3',('python@ws', '/opt/project/script.py')))
        # os._exit(os.execv('/usr/bin/su',('login@ws', '-', 'eri')))

    stdin = os.fdopen(master, 'wb+', buffering=0)
    fl = fcntl.fcntl(master, fcntl.F_GETFL)
    fcntl.fcntl(master, fcntl.F_SETFL, fl | os.O_NONBLOCK)

    def pipe_data_received(ws):
        data = stdin.read()
        try:
            asyncio.ensure_future(ws.send_str(data.decode()))
        except:
            os.kill(pid,15)

    loop.add_reader(master, pipe_data_received, ws) # читаем консоль
    async for msg in ws: # читаем ввод пользователя
        if msg.type == aiohttp.WSMsgType.TEXT:
            stdin.write(msg.data.encode())
        elif msg.type == aiohttp.WSMsgType.BINARY:
            stdin.write(msg.data)
        elif msg.type == aiohttp.WSMsgType.CLOSE:
            await ws.close()
            os.kill(pid,15)
        elif msg.type == aiohttp.WSMsgType.CLOSED:
            os.kill(pid,15)
        elif msg.type == aiohttp.WSMsgType.ERROR:
            os.kill(pid,15)

    os.kill(pid,15)
    os.waitpid(pid, 0)
    return ws


app = web.Application()
app.add_routes([web.get('/term', websocket_handler)])
web.run_app(app)
```

```html
<!doctype html>
  <html style="padding:0;margin:0">
    <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/xterm/css/xterm.css" />
      <script src="node_modules/xterm/lib/xterm.js"></script>
      <script src="node_modules/xterm-addon-fit/lib/xterm-addon-fit.js"></script>
      <script src="node_modules/xterm-addon-attach/lib/xterm-addon-attach.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body style="padding:0;margin:0">
      <div id="terminal"  style="height:100vh"></div>
      <script>
    const term = new Terminal();
    const socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080/term');
    const attachAddon = new AttachAddon.AttachAddon(socket);
    const fitAddon = new FitAddon.FitAddon();
    term.loadAddon(fitAddon);
    term.loadAddon(attachAddon);
    term.open(document.getElementById('terminal'));
    fitAddon.fit();
      </script>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Запускается экземпляр питона, на вэб сокете соединяет с яваскриптом на сайте и можно в реальном времени поработать с консолью python или укажите параметры запуска вашего скрипта.

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/474973)

Comment: Ок, там вроде не так много кода...