# Передача данных из php/js в python скрипт

Tags: javascript, python

Вопрос заключается в следующем. Я создаю сайт для обучения основам ИИ, соответственно есть необходимость встроить возможность выполнения на сайте кусков кода, которые напишет пользователь и, соответственно, необходимость проверки того, что вывелось эталону. Необходимо реализовать передачу данных из браузера непосредственно на сервер, где бы выполнялся скрипт пользователя, который он написал. Как это сделать?

[Нашел вот это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1123528/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-python-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B5-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3-%D0%B2%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81), но никто по существу не ответил... Необходимо передать данные непосредственно в input() а не в качестве аргументов

Answer (score 0):

Если бэкэнд на, допустим, `Flask`, то создаем обработчик:

```
from flask import request

@app.route('/code-handle', methods=['POST'])
def on_code_handle():
   data = request.json # here's our data from frontend
   # do some staff
   return 'Ok', 200
```

И теперь на этот обработчик надо с фронтенда отправить данные (средствами JS). Например вот так:

```
fetch("/code-handle", {
  method: "post",
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },

  body: JSON.stringify({
     code: 'HERE IS SOME CODE FROM FRONTEND'
  })
})
.then( (response) => { 
   // Response from backend
});
```

Это эталонное решение. Передавать в `input()` это нужно писать костыли, которые ваш `request` с фронтенда будут переводить на `stdin` скрипта `python`.

## P.S.

если встанет вопрос обработки решений на различных языках, то советую использовать Ejudge :)

Comment: И как эту строку, преобразованную в json затем запустить в виде скрипта на сервере? Насколько это безопасно?

Comment: Запустить?) Просто - `eval(string)`, но никогда так не делайте -- это небезопасно. А тема проверки заданий пользователей является актуальной на хакатонах до сих пор. Некоторые пишут свои, а некоторые берут `Ejudge`. `Ejudge` долго и муторно поднимать + для него нужно по хорошему патчить ядро линукса, но зато это надежное решение для проверки пользовательского кода.

Comment: Насколько я понял, автору надо запускать Питон-скрипты от пользователей на своем сервере, в этом и вопрос. При чем не просто абстрактные скрипты, а те, которые будут взаимодействовать с данными на том же сервере (или как у вас там с ИИ работают)))). И еще: а `indentations` ваши все не пропадут при пересылке строки? Код адекватно будет работать?

Comment: @Leonid, засуньте код в `base64` и будет вам счастье. А вообще и без него не должны пропадать. Просто так запускать скрипты на сервере нельзя, иначе любой школьник который знает как работать с файлами через `Python` убьет сервер за 15 минут.

Comment: Ну вот в этом вся проблема, мне не нужно тестирование как таковое, это по сути дела мини кейсы, которые точно дают заранее известный ответ, просто вопрос стоит в том, чтобы запустить скрипт безопасно и каким то образом скормить ему тот инпут, который введет пользователь (соответственно получить ответ и сравнить с эталонным, при несовпадении или ошибке выводить ошибку, а при совпадении говорить что все ок и поехали к следующему кейсу)

Comment: @РоманКочешков, скрипт пишет пользователь?

Comment: @icYFTL, да, я преследую такую логику - пользователь пишет скрипт - решение предложенной задачи, он сохраняется в файл, и на сервере уже непосредственно выполняется, при этом необходимо как то в этот файл передать входные данные, которые тоже пользователь вводит (в идеале полностью интерактив, а не просто набрал данные и они отправились). Ну может быть возможна прослойка - один файл неизменный в который отправляется инпут от пользователя и он уже непосредственно передает его в скрипт пользователя каким то танцами с бубном, но какими - я не знаю и пытаюсь выяснить....

Comment: @РоманКочешков, в таком случае я могу отправить в качестве скрипта `exec('from os import system; system("ls");')` и оно выполнится. А могу отправить команду rm с аргументами и параметром корня. НеБеЗоПаСнО.

Comment: @icYFTL, я понимаю, забыл упомянуть что это наверное еще должно быть и безопасно) XD

Comment: @РоманКочешков, гуглите в сторону `Ejudge`. Потом уже будем по факту разбираться :D